# Partial string matching & replacement in R

Tags: r, string-matching, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe like this

```
> myDataFrame
           company
1   Investment LLC
2    Hyperloop LLC
3 Invezzstment LLC
4   Investment_LLC
5   Haiperloop LLC
6   Inwestment LLC
```

I need to match all these fuzzy strings, so the end result should look like this:

```
> myDataFrame
           company
1   Investment LLC
2    Hyperloop LLC
3   Investment LLC
4   Investment LLC
5    Hyperloop LLC
6   Investment LLC
```

So, actually, I must solve a partial match-and-replace task for categorical variable. There are a lot great functions in base R and packages to solve string matching, but I'm stuck to find a single solution for this kind of match-and-replace.
I don't care which occurrence will replace other, for example "Investment LLC" or "Invezzstment LLC" are both equally fine. Just need them to be *consistent*.

Is there any single all-in-one function or a loop for this?

Comment: Can you describe what you have tried so far? For instance why is base::agrep not working for you?

Comment: Dear @Calimo, base::agrep in working totally fine in finding similar strings, but I can't force him to replace strings line-by-line. I tried some for and while loops, but with no luck. The algorithm should be as follows: 1) R finds a string in vector 2) compares it with other strings is vector 3) every string that is similar to it (with some distance measurement provided), must be replaced with that string.

Comment: Please post the code you already have so we can take it from there. By the way, I understand from your comment on the answer that choosing the misspelled `Invezzstment LLC` would be OK?

Comment: @Calimo, I deleted this code, and it was (unluckily) not saved in my git during commits. Anyway, there was little use of it, because it was not valid. I remember that I used `sapply` with partial match function (I think `agrep`). "Invezzstment LLC" is totally ok. In fact, Invezzstment LLC & Investment LLC are the same thing; I need R to take **any** of those and replace all other occurrences, so I have **one** nice categorical variable for this one category. When you have more than 50000 records & 1200 unique values in it, it's would a tedious job to figure out any misspelled variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some time I ended up with this dumb code. *Attention*: It is **not** fully automating the process of replacement, because every time the proper matches should be verified by human, and every time we need a fine tune of agrep `max.distance` argument. I am totally sure there are ways to make it better and quicker, but this can help to get the job done.

```
    ##########
    # Manual renaming with partial matches
    ##########

    # a) Take a look at the desired column of factor variables
    sort(unique(MYDATA$names))   # take a look

    # ****
    Sensthreshold <- 0.2   # sensitivity of agrep, usually 0.1-0.2 get it right
    Searchstring <- "Invesstment LLC"   # what should I search?
    # ****

    # User-defined function: returns similar string on query in column
    Searcher <- function(input, similarity = 0.1) {
      unique(agrep(input, 
                   MYDATA$names,   # <-- define your column here
                   ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE,
                   max.distance = similarity))
    }

    # b) Make a search of desired string
    Searcher(Searchstring, Sensthreshold)   # using user-def function 
    ### PLEASE INSPECT THE OUTPUT OF THE SEARCH
    ### Did it get it right?

 =============================================================================#
    ## ACTION! This changes your dataframe!
    ## Please make backup before proceeding
    ## Please execute this code as a whole to avoid errors

    # c) Make a vector of cells indexes after checking output
    vector_of_cells <- agrep(Searchstring, 
                       MYDATA$names, ignore.case = TRUE,
                       max.distance = Sensthreshold)
    # d) Apply the changes
    MYDATA$names[vector_of_cells] <- Searchstring # <--- CHANGING STRING
    # e) Check result
    unique(agrep(Searchstring, MYDATA$names, 
                 ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE, max.distance = Sensthreshold))
=============================================================================#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector of correct spellings, `agrep` makes this reasonably easy:

```
myDataFrame$company <- sapply(myDataFrame$company, 
                              function(val){agrep(val, 
                                                  c('Investment LLC', 'Hyperloop LLC'), 
                                                  value = TRUE)})

myDataFrame
#          company
# 1 Investment LLC
# 2  Hyperloop LLC
# 3 Investment LLC
# 4 Investment LLC
# 5  Hyperloop LLC
# 6 Investment LLC
```

If you don't have such a vector, you can likely make one with clever application of `adist` or even just `table` if the correct spelling is repeated more than the others, which it likely will be (though isn't here).

Comment: Thank you for you response, alistaire! I have no vector of correctly spelled entites. I tried your suggestion about adist function, however, R cannot compute this string distance matrix due to n of records = 59396, so this large matrix object exceeds 26.3 Gb. Table is a good idea, I shall try that.